# PHP session side-effect warning with global variables as a source of data

Tags: php, session, global-variables, session-variables

I'm trying to host a PHP web site that was given to me.  I see this warning:

> **Warning:** Unknown: Your script possibly
>   relies on a session side-effect which
>   existed until PHP 4.2.3. Please be
>   advised that the session extension
>   does not consider global variables as
>   a source of data, unless
>   register_globals is enabled. You can
>   disable this functionality and this
>   warning by setting
>   session.bug_compat_42 or
>   session.bug_compat_warn to off,
>   respectively. in **Unknown** on line **0**

What does this mean?  How might I track down the source of this problem within the code?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

basically you have a variable with the same name as your session. ex:

```
$_SESSION['var1'] = null;
$var1 = 'something';
```

which will reproduce this error. you can stop PHP from trying to find existing variables and warning you about them by adding these lines to your script:

```
ini_set('session.bug_compat_warn', 0);
ini_set('session.bug_compat_42', 0);
```

these values can be set in php.ini or .htaccess as well

Comment: Works like a charm! Thumbs up!

Comment: For people who are not that great at modifying php.ini files, the format above isn't what you use.  It should be "session.bug_compat_42 = 0" on one line and "session.bug_compat_warn = 0" on another (no quotes).  Do a search in your php.ini file first, though.  It's likely both have already been defined as 1 and you just need to switch to 0

Answer (score 6):

There seem to be a few problematic possibilities here:

http://www.spiration.co.uk/post/1231/Your-script-possibly-relies-on-a-session-side-effect

says that cases like this:

```
$_SESSION['firstname']=$_REQUEST['firstname'];
```

will trigger the warning.

Additionally, I interpret this php bug content: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41540 to mean that this error may also occur when you assign a variable to the session superglobal that is not yet initialized, e.g.

```
//Start of script
$_SESSION['bob'] = $bob;
```

Answer (score 5):

This is good information on finding out what's causing the warning, but I would recommend NOT shutting off the warnings Owen mentions. These runtime functions are [removed in PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) and the developer should get into the practice of avoiding such usage of variables.

To fix this, it may be a pain on the developers end, but if you have

```
$_SESSION["user"]
$user;
```

rename the session to

```
$_SESSION["sessuser"];
```

Or vise-versa just as long as the session name and the variable name are different. Think of it this way: when you upgrade to the latest build, you'll have to debug your code anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

When you are making changes to the .htaccess ini_set does not work. You will need to do it as:

```
php_flag session.bug_compat_42 0
php_flag session.bug_compat_warn 0
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case,  php.ini change from on to off

like this :

```
session.bug_compat_42 = off
session.bug_compat_warn = off
```

if not working, restart apache