# PHP: Bug narrowed down to one line, can't figure it out

Tags: php

So This part of my code:

```
print_r($_SESSION['T']);
$T = array_values($data2);
print_r($_SESSION['T']);
```

Outputs this:

```
Array ( [0] => NZL ) Array ( [0] => ENG [1] => NZL )
```

That line is the first time $T is declared. As far as I can tell there should be NO reason for  $_SESSION['T'] to gain an entry and its definitely causing me problems.
Might be good to note that after that array_values call, the var $T looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => ENG [1] => NZL )
```

Which is what the second print of $_SESSION['T'] is displaying.

Let me know if you can think of any reason this might be happening, thanks

Comment: I think this is the good ole "session side effect" bug. Hang on, I'll see whether I can find the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you might have [Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) turned on.

```
if (ini_get('register_globals')) {
    die("Register Globals is ON - This is BAD");
}
else  {
    die("Register Globals is OFF - This is GOOD");
}
```

The idea was that - with register globals - you could use a variable `$T` as a shorthand for `$_GLOBALS['T']`... or `$_GET['T']` or `$_POST['T']` or (of course) `$_SESSION['T']`.

If it sounds like a bad idea, that's because it is (was) and has now been so aggressively discouraged that it is deprecated and usually off by default.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug/side-effect. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175091/php-session-side-effect-warning-with-global-variables-as-a-source-of-data) for details. It should be sortable by setting `register_globals` to off.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused because you have `register_globals` set to `on` (Which is absolutely terrible). (See http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

You should disable register globals so that the SESSION/POST/GET/REQUEST/COOKIE variables do not interfere.