# How to register global variables for php sessions

Tags: php, session, global

i get this error:

Warning: Unknown: Your script possibly relies on a session side-effect which existed until PHP 4.2.3. Please be advised that the session extension does not consider global variables as a source of data, unless register_globals is enabled. You can disable this functionality and this warning by setting session.bug_compat_42 or session.bug_compat_warn to off, respectively in Unknown on line 0

According to it, i have to enable(register) the global variables right?  How do I do so, and why is the error occurring in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you calling session_start() at the VERY top of your PHP document?

The PHP manual says that the session_register() function has been deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0 and reliance on it is highly discouraged.

Instead, do something like

$_SESSION['dog'] = "Woof";

But you must be calling session_start() before anything else in your document!

Comment: yes, at the top of every script, i have the session_start( ) right at top as the first line of code.

Comment: Do any of your variables in your script share the same name as one of your SESSION variables?

Comment: so you mean once a user gets's to homepage, i have to call session_start( )?  even if they haven't entered any form data?

Comment: Like $dog = "woof" and $_SESSION["dog"] = "bark". this problem will produce that error you're getting

Comment: @jonathan let me check on that.

Comment: yes, on all pages that you want to be able to access your SESSION variables, you should enable sessions

Comment: alternatively, you can disable that warning if you'd like. somewhere in your php.ini file, add these lines:
ini_set('session.bug_compat_warn', 0);
ini_set('session.bug_compat_42', 0);

Comment: You don't have to do session_start() at the very top of the doc. It can be anywhere, just as long as it's before the script generates any output.

Comment: OMG UR RIGHT, WELL SORT OF...it just means that the session array variable was set to a variable not initiated or declared...you get the point my friend.

Answer (score 0):

after enabling register_globals in PHP directive.

use `session_start()` at starting of php

```
$barney = "you can try this";
session_register("barney");

// Use of $_SESSION is preferred, as of PHP 4.1.0
$_SESSION["hotel"] = "Starling";

// The old way was to use $HTTP_SESSION_VARS
$HTTP_SESSION_VARS["email"] = "neo@gmail.com";
```

Answer (score -1):

Register globals was a way for variables from _POST/_GET/_SESSION to be defined into global scope under their own name.  I've never used or seen usage of variables coming from _SESSION... but the solution is the same.  PHP should be announcing the file path & line so all you need to do is refactor your code to stop relying on this deprecated feature.

Comment: @Dave - Jonathan is actually closer to your solution.  Get rid of all session_register calls and replace session_register("someVar") with _SESSION['someVar'] = $someVar;

Comment: yes i gave him the point, and down pointed you.  The problem was that i set a session array index to an uninitiated variable.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like register_globals is set to "Off" in you php.ini file.  If you have access to it you can change this.  This thread is also relevant:

[php-session-side-effect-warning-with-global-variables-as-a-source-of-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175091/php-session-side-effect-warning-with-global-variables-as-a-source-of-data)

Answer (score -1):

Global variables are no longer considered normal use.  They can cause all kinds of management issues, memory allocation problems.  PHP common practice is to use Session variables instead ($_SESSION["variable_name"]).  If you really have your heart set on Globals, you can enable them in php.ini.