# PHP session not registering

Tags: session, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP session side-effect warning with global variables as a source of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175091/php-session-side-effect-warning-with-global-variables-as-a-source-of-data)

I have a problem with a login script that im using. problem is with some of the hosting providers after login the session is not registering. and in php error logs i can see this error

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: Your script possibly relies on a session side-effect which existed until PHP 4.2.3. Please be advised that the session extension does not consider global variables as a source of data, unless register_globals is enabled. You can disable this functionality and this warning by setting session.bug_compat_42 or session.bug_compat_warn to off, respectively in Unknown on line 0

but in most of the hosting's like bluehost, hostmonster it works fine without any error. can someone point me out what is the wrong thing im doing here? thank you in advanced.

*Code:*

```
<?
session_start();
ob_start();
?>

        <?php
        $err=isset($_GET['error'])?$_GET['error']:""; 
        if($err=='error'){?>
        <div class="errormsgbox">Wrong Username or Password. Please try again.</div>    
        <?php }

        if(!isset($_SESSION['adminuser'])){
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        {
        // username and password sent from Form
        $adminuser=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adminuser']); 
        $adminpassword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adminpassword']); 
        $gpassword=md5($adminpassword); // Encrypted Password
        $sql="SELECT id FROM admin WHERE adminuser='$adminuser' and adminpassword='$gpassword'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

        // If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
        if($count==1)
        {

        session_register("adminuser");

        header("location:index.php");
        }
        else
        {
        header("location:login.php?error=error");

        }
        }
        ob_end_flush();

        ?>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
    <div class="login_input">
    <label class="loginlbl"  for="adminuser">UserName :</label>
    <input type="text" name="adminuser"/>
    </div>
    <div class="login_input">
    <label class="loginlbl"  for="adminpassword">Password :</label>
    <input type="password" name="adminpassword"/>
    </div>
    <div class="login_submit">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value=" Login to Admin Contol Panel"/>
    </div>
    </form>
    <?php }else{
    header("location:index.php");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175091/php-session-side-effect-warning-with-global-variables-as-a-source-of-data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175091/php-session-side-effect-warning-with-global-variables-as-a-source-of-data

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `session_register` is deprecated as says in [PHP:SESSION_REGISTER](http://php.net/session_register)

You should use:

```
//session_register("adminuser"); //deprecated
$_SESSION["adminuser"] = $adminuser;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing `<?` with `<?php` - it may be your hoster disabled so called short-tags, therefore that part is never executed. It's basically good habit to never use short tags

**EDIT**

You can disable this warning by adding this:

```
ini_set('session.bug_compat_warn', 0);
ini_set('session.bug_compat_42', 0);
```

or fix your code to not use the same name script variable and session key, i.e. this would trigger this warning:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = false;
$foo = 0;
```

a heritage from PHP4 ages...

Comment: Also remove the useless `?>     <?php` from lines 4-6 as you're just introducing whitespace that will cause errors if any of your code needs to modify headers.

Comment: Correct. Using `?>` should be limited to the case where you **know** you **need** to close PHP block by hand. Otherwise left it open as will be automatically closed by the end of file

Answer (score 3):

The manual on [`session_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php):

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of
>   PHP 5.4.0.

Just use `$_SESSION['adminuser']` as you would use any other variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a variable that has the same name like a normal variable.

```
$_SESSION['yourvar'] = null;
$yourvar = 'something';
```

[PHP session side-effect warning with global variables as a source of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175091/php-session-side-effect-warning-with-global-variables-as-a-source-of-data)

**And:**

**session_register** is deprecated use `$_SESSION['yourvar']` instead. The function session register causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer, but a warning that won't fit in a comment:

You're doing the password processing backwards. You're escaping, THEN md5-ing. This is incorrect. Consider a simple password:

```
o'brien
```

which gets escaped to

```
o\'brien
```

and then md5'd. That backslash will become PART of the hash value:

```
o'brien -> 255740509ca6c0e7d86c88fc4d8ddf9d
o\'brien -> afd5c6601a6df7e48d0ce5584b10bf12
```

note that the hash values are utterly different. This could turn around and bite you if you're comparing hashed values elsewhere and forget the escaping stage.