# Php form not registering

Tags: php, pdo

I think im utilizing php oop right, however its not redirecting the page to the profile.php page it just goes blank after i submit.

No error message shows, i wonder what im dong wrong.

Could it be a [session problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516268/php-session-not-registering) ?

index.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
require_once 'layouts/header.php';
require_once 'User.php';

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['btn-signup']) ){

    $username = htmlentities($_POST['txt-username']);
    $unpass = htmlentities($_POST['txt-password']);
    $password = password_hash($unpass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 12] );
    $unemail = $_POST['txt-email'];
    $email = filter_var($unemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

    $guest = new User();

    if($username ==""){
        echo "Enter a Username";

    }

    if($email == ""){
        echo "Enter a Email";
    }

    if($password == ""){
        echo "Enter a Password";
    }

    elseif($guest->signup($email,$password,$username)){
        header("Location:profile.php");
    }
}


?>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <form action ="" method="POST">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="txt-email" placeholder="Enter email">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt-username" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="txt-username" placeholder="Enter Username">
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txt-password" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="txt-password" placeholder="Enter email">
                  </div>


                     <button type="submit" name="btn-signup" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>


        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

User.php

```
<?php

require_once 'Db.php';

class User extends Db{

    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Db();

    }


    public function signup($email, $password, $username)
    {
        try{
            $stmt = $this->db->connect->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_email, user_pass, user_name) VALUES (:email, :password, :username) ");

            $stmt->bindparam(':email', $email);
            $stmt->bindparam(':password', $password);
            $stmt->bindparam(':username', $username);
            $stmt->execute();

        }

        catch(PDOExeception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }


    }


}
```

Db.php

```
<?php 

error_reporting(-1);

class Db{

    private $db_host;
    private $db_user;
    private $db_name;
    private $db_pass;

    public function connect()
    {
        $this->db_host = "127.0.0.1";
        $this->db_user = "root";
        $this->db_pass = "root";
        $this->db_name = "eli9";

        try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8889,dbname=eli9", 'root', 'root');
            $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            echo "connected \n";


        } 
        catch (PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }


        return $db;

    }


}
```

Comment: This won't fix your code but don't use `htmlentities()` against passwords (or any other form of manipulation) since it could do more damage than good when using `password_verify()` and will fail. You also gave the inputs 2x name attributes of the same.

Comment: thanks fred, i will keep that in mine.

Comment: welcome. Well, TBH I'm not very good with OOP stuff but if you're getting a blank page, it could be caused by a return somewhere. I'd have to copy and test your code but I won't be able to tonight and will give it a try tomorrow, unless I seen a solution posted.

Comment: I also mentioned that two of your inputs have `name="xxx"` twice; you need to remove one of them from those. That could be having some adverse effects.

Comment: i deleted the duplicates name inputs, however now, i get a white screen again... i even changed 'btn-signup to `'btn_signup'`

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` must be placed at the very beginning of a script before it produce any visible output. But in your case, it seems that

```
require_once 'layouts/header.php';
```

might have some html or other output. Place the `session_start()` code on top of that could solve your problem.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
session_start();
require_once 'layouts/header.php';
require_once 'User.php';

if (isset($_POST['btn-signup']) ){

    $username = htmlentities($_POST['txt-username']);
    $unpass = htmlentities($_POST['txt-password']);
    $password = password_hash($unpass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 12] );
    $unemail = $_POST['txt-email'];
    $email = filter_var($unemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

    $guest = new User();

    if($username ==""){
        echo "Enter a Username";

    }

    if($email == ""){
        echo "Enter a Email";
    }

    if($password == ""){
        echo "Enter a Password";
    }

    elseif($guest->signup($email,$password,$username)){
        header("Location:profile.php");
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: still didnt work i did what you said. i put the `session_start()` at the top and nothing happened still

Comment: Oh, I see. There is also a big problem in your button and field name. You can not put dash (`-`) on name. please replace them with underscore in your form and script.

Comment: *"You can not put dash (-) on name. please replace them with underscore in your form and script."* - @Chayan That is false. Name attributes can contain hyphens, just not variables, since PHP would interpret `$var-x` as `var minus x`, not name attributes. You shouldn't pass off false information like that (and to the OP) and it will not fix their code.

Comment: @Chayan thanks it works nowww :))) thank you chayan and fred

Comment: @OwlMan are you saying that changing the hyphens to underscores worked? if not, what did?

Comment: @OwlMan I've never had problems with name attributes with hyphens, variables yes. I'm baffled. If anything, error reporting would have thrown you something about those.

Comment: @fred heres the thing though, changing it to underscore gave me a different result, and that is now a white screen that says enter `username`, which i did. so im doing some work on my end to figure out why the form didnt get sent to the database

Comment: I quote from https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-cdata *"ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), **hyphens ("-"),** underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")."* @OwlMan and Chayan.