# PHP Session warning issue

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP session side-effect warning with global variables as a source of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175091/php-session-side-effect-warning-with-global-variables-as-a-source-of-data)

I am getting following warning from `php`

*`Warning: Unknown: Your script possibly relies on a session side-effect
 which existed until 
 PHP 4.2.3. Please be advised that the session extension does not 
 consider global variables as a source of data, unless 
 register_globals is enabled. You can disable this functionality 
 and this warning by setting session.bug_compat_42 or 
 session.bug_compat_warn to off, respectively in Unknown on line 0`*

I believe the following codes created the warning.

```
 $name=$_SESSION['name'];
 $emails=$_SESSION['email'];

 $_SESSION['info']=array_intersect($name, $emails);
```

I have no access to `php.ini` nor server. I can only change my codes. 
Are there anyways to  remove the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means you have a variable with the same name as your session variable is as below.

```
$_SESSION['variable'] = null;
$variable = 'data';
```

You can stop PHP from trying to find existing variables and warning you about them by adding these lines to your script in php.ini or .htaccess

```
ini_set('session.bug_compat_warn', 0);
ini_set('session.bug_compat_42', 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will remove the error:

```
ini_set('session.bug_compat_42',0);
ini_set('session.bug_compat_warn',0);
```

You may also be able to turn it off from within your .htaccess file or, if available, a php.ini file in the root of your directory.

Comment: Is just suppressing the error a good idea?  It seems like it might come back to haunt them later.

Comment: @GigaWatt true. I would update the question but I'll just vote to close due to being a dupe.