# Session register_globals warning in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP session side-effect warning with global variables as a source of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175091/php-session-side-effect-warning-with-global-variables-as-a-source-of-data)

I am getting response from Ajax via PHP. 
I am getting this error:

> **PHP Warning:**  Unknown: Your script possibly relies 
>   on a session side-effect which existed until PHP 4.2.3.
>   Please be advised that the session extension does not
>   consider global variables as a source of data, unless
>   register_globals is enabled. You can disable this
>   functionality and this warning by setting session.bug_compat_42
>   or session.bug_compat_warn to off, respectively in Unknown
>   on line 0

How can I solve it?

My PHP script is

```
<?php

    include("include/config.inc.php");

    $name = $_POST['loginname'];
    $phone = $_POST['logintelephone'];

    // To protect MySQL injection
    $name = stripslashes($name);
    $phone = stripslashes($phone);
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
    $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($phone);

    $query  = mysql_query("select * from chatapp_users where name = '$name' and phone_no  = '$phone'");
    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($query);
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count > 0){
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['currentuser'] = $name;
        $_SESSION['currentuserid'] = $result['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['phone'] = $result['phone'];
        echo 1;
    }else {
        echo 2;
    }
?>
```

Comment: As the notice says: this is a _Warning_, not an _Error_. And it comes with a pefectly fine explanation of what it is about. So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could set "session.bug_compat_warn = off" in your php.ini. This should turn off that warning.

Another solution would be to update PHP to something higher than version 4.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Two more solutions:

- Put your code in functions.

  Variables in functions are not (unless you use the `global` statement) in the global namespace, thus this error is not displayed.
- Do not use variables with the same name as (used) session indexes. In this case, rename either `$phone` or `$_SESSION['phone']`

There are also other (disturbing) details about this warning in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2262847/1244588).