# PHP declaring global and session variables

Tags: php, global-variables, session-variables

I'm been using PHP5.3.8 for a while now and I've just come across a new error for me;

> Warning: Unknown: Your script possibly relies on a session side-effect
>   which existed until PHP 4.2.3. Please be advised that the session
>   extension does not consider global variables as a source of data,
>   unless register_globals is enabled. You can disable this functionality
>   and this warning by setting session.bug_compat_42 or
>   session.bug_compat_warn to off, respectively. in Unknown on line 0

To which there is a solution to here; [PHP session side-effect warning with global variables as a source of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175091/php-session-side-effect-warning-with-global-variables-as-a-source-of-data/175145#175145).

However, I still don't understand ***why*** this is happening. As far as I'm aware, there should be no ambiguity between `$foo` and `$_SESSION['foo']`?

I've tried testing a few of the scripts online that people say throw this error, but they don't throw the warning on my system, and the script I'm getting this warning on is hella complicated and stripping it down to a few lines in order to replicate the error is proving problematic.

However, I have narrowed it down to one line;

```
$bonus = isset($_GET['bonus']) ? $_GET['bonus'] : '';
```

`$_SESSION['bonus']` is set to `null` in a previous page, and register_globals has been off since about PHP4.2 something, so can't be the $_GET scope.

So this brings me back to my first point; why is there suddenly an issue between `$bonus` and `$_SESSION['bonus']`? I say suddenly, because I am using this exact script on another site (same box) and I get no errors.

Could someone point me to anywhere that perhaps explains in more detail how PHP deals with session vars etc and why there is an issue between the two variables?

Thanks.

[**Update**]

Looking here; [PHP Runtime Configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.bug-compat-42) it does mention that:

> [PHP has...] an undocumented feature/bug that allows you to initialize a session variable
>   in the global scope...

I guess there may not be much more to say other than that. It just seems odd to me that PHP has issues with `$_SESSION['foo']`/`$foo` when `$_SESSION['foo'] != $foo`...

Comment: The question is not clear enough to me.

Comment: @HermannStephaneNtsamo the question is; why does declaring a variable of the same name as a session variable throw this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `session.bug_compat_42` to off, it will turn off the functionality the warning is about. c.f. http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Comment: Hi Adder, thanks for the link, I know how to turn off the warning, but I'm just looking for a little more info on exactly why it occurs, rather than ignoring it.

Comment: Well, as I read the documentation, you can assign to the global `$alert` to set `$_SESSION['alert']` if the feature is on. And `session.bug_compat_42` does not turn off the warning it turns of the feature.